# MySQL biggest value in column PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the biggest value of a certain column. This is my code that I got on a turorial.

```
$query = "SELECT type, MAX(ID) FROM sessions GROUP BY Status"; 

$result = mysql_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "The biggest session ID is " .$row['MAX(ID)'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

I need to get the greatest ID number in the table. The status is just another column that I think should be unrelated to finding the greatest number in the ID column. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @neal off topic, but is there ever really a good reason to choose mysqli (over pdo)? is it even worth mentioning anymore? newbies should use pdo so mysqli can go away.

Comment: @sgroves there is **nothing wrong** with `mysqli_*`

Comment: Some people despise the bloated, disgusting API, feature-missing PDO. Simple as that.

Comment: @neal besides the fact that it's harder to use than pdo and only works with php? yes, it *works* fine, but i don't see a reason to ever recommend it over pdo (or confuse a newbie by telling them to pick)

Comment: @sgroves i took the snippet from here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php (ask them for more info...)

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for the maximum id in the table the query should be:

```
 SELECT max(ID) from sessions;
```

Your group by column will give your the maximum id for each unique value of Status, and if you are grouping by status to get any meaningful results you should also have that as one of the selection fields like.

```
 SELECT Status, max(ID) from sessions group by Status
```

Answer (score 0):

Alias your MAX(ID) function call to a column name in your query;

```
SELECT type, MAX(ID) AS max_id FROM sessions GROUP BY status
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the full data from the specific row with the biggest id, you can do:

```
 $query = "SELECT type, MAX(ID) 
           FROM sessions 
           WHERE ID = MAX(ID) 
           GROUP BY Status";
```

Answer (score 0):

> The status is just another column that I think should be unrelated to finding the greatest number in the ID column.

The problem is that `MAX()` is an aggregate function that will return the max id *per group* as per your `GROUP BY` clause. So it doesn't make sense to SELECT `type, MAX(ID)` and then `GROUP BY Status`. If you want the max id per type, you want `GROUP BY type`.

Except in the very rare advanced situation where the feature can be abused, it never makes sense to select a column (like `type`) but then `GROUP BY` something else (like `Status`). In fact, most databases do not allow you to do this; some people consider it a bug/bad feature that mysql allows this type of query at all.